# Two recruiters offered me the same position – should I tell them when I refuse?

Tags: recruitment

I have been contacted by two separate recruiters on the same day, for two different opportunities in separate companies and different cities.

However, the two companies are subsidiaries of the same large global company, and both positions are listed on their global career site. Moreso, the position is exactly the same in terms of work tasks and responsibilities, and it's even in the same market niche.

I am going to reject both offers, but I'd like to stay on good terms with at least one of the recruiters. Should I disclose that I have been in contact for basically the same position (but in a different subsidiary)?

A [similar question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/how-to-deal-with-a-potential-turf-war-between-three-recruiters-for-the-same-job) has already been asked, although mine differs in a few key areas:

- I have not signed anything
- I have not received a formal job offer
- I am not going to pursue the opportunities
- It's not 100% the same position, though it's within the same parent
  corporation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decline, citing lack of interest in a change at this point in time.

As a side note, keep in mind that job descriptions in a corporate environment are standardized and that goes double if HR is centralized. This means that two different positions may have the same job description but they are different positions because you will be reporting to different people. The way to apply to two different positions is to apply for each separately - the fact that they have the same job description is irrelevant. And until you are explicitly told otherwise, assume that hiring managers operate as silos.

Answer (score 1):

You have not signed anything;
The jobs are publicly posted;
You only want to stay on good terms with one of the recruiters; and
You don't want the job.

Tell both recruiters you are not interested in that particular job.  Remind them that this was a publicly posted job...because a good recruiter is not simply calling to tell you they saw a job posted publicly somewhere.  A good recruiter should be finding jobs because they have contacts in the environment their clients are seeking opportunities.  They should have relationships with people in companies and industries they are active within.

If you want to work with a recruiter find a good one.  Let them know specifically what your interests are.  Find out how they will go about getting you opportunities.  A quality recruiter is a bonus to your job search.  Many recruiters specialize in specific career areas and actually have work experience in that area.  They can assist you in creating a better resume and in building up marketable skills.  Even a good recruiter can only do so much for you if you are lacking skills or have a poor quality resume.  The whole point of a recruiter is to save you time and effort screening potential positions.